# append the variable into mysql table data

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to append the variable into mysql data.

```
$update1 = "UPDATE review_words SET adjective = CONCAT(adjective, $adjective), noun = CONCAT(noun, 'qw') ";
```

It works well when I using any string like 'som text' but when I use php variable it gives error.

For above query noun is ok but `$adjective` gives error:

```
Error: Unknown column 'top' in 'field list'
```

where $adjetive = 'top, nice, cool'

Also I want to append `' '` space before appeding any new variable value

Comment: add quotes around `'$adjective'` for space try this `CONCAT(adjective, ' ','$adjective')`

Comment: Can you please see last line in my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't quote your variable so mysql try to find a column instead of your values

```
$update1 = "UPDATE review_words SET adjective = CONCAT(adjective, ' ', '$adjective'), noun = CONCAT(noun, 'qw') ";
```

Also Concat can use a delimiter as second argument.